# Regex for Git commit Date

Tags: regex, git, parsing

I want to get all the Dates from a git log. For example if i do

```
git log
```

i'm getting

```
...
commit foofoofoofoofoomorefoos
Author: pragmaticus <foo@foo.tld>
Date:   Fri Feb 24 19:58:19 2017 +0100
...
```

To extract the Date i'm using following regular expression

```
(\w{3} \w{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4})
```

which leads to

```
Fri Feb 24 19:58:19 2017
```

As you can see the regex is pretty long. Is there a way to form a less verbose pattern?

---

**Update**

As @bejado suggested in the comments i replaced all [0-9] tokens with \d

```
(\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4})
```

There a still many repetitive tokens. How far can we go, to make it even shorter?

---

**Update**

Shortest Regex by @MohaMed so far

```
^Date:\s*(.*)\s[\+\-].*$
```

I like the way how the pattern tests for the String "Date:" and the "+/-" sign at the end.

Comment: You can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]` (they're not 100% the same, but for your use case it's fine)

Comment: Don't do it that way. Use `git log --format=...` and select a format that delivers the date in an easily parsed fashion (and avoiding arbitrary text like log messages entirely). Your best bet is probably to use ISO 8601. (And, incidentally, if you already have the hash ID and are looking for one specific commit, use `--no-walk` as well to get just the interesting data from the one specific commit.)

Comment: Shortest Regex ^Date:\s*(.*)\s\+.*$

Comment: @torek Thanks for your input, but i don't want to mess with the `git log` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty stable and short regex, as suggested by @MohaMad

```
^Date:\s*(.*)\s[\+\-].*$
```

By changing the format of the git log output i can even eliminate the need of a regular expression, by just printing out the dates (Thanks to @torek).

```
git log --format="%ad"
```

Comment: Note that regex is working for positive offset '+' timezones. Change \+ to [\+\-] , to match any timezone date logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: \w{3} \w{3} [0-9\s:]*, but I believe torek's response is better.

Comment: Pretty short regex. But i fear it would match other lines in the git log output.